# R Large Matrix Size differences

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I have a large correlation matrix, 62589x62589. I've binarised the matrix above a certain threshold which I've done with no problems but I'm slightly confused as to the significant difference in basic Calculation time.

The first time I did this.... number of 1's : 425,491 ... Number of 0's : 3,916,957,430
Sum of these two numbers == 62589^2, implying that the matrix is truly binarised. I saved this as an Rdata object (31Mb). Performing a basic calculation of the matrix takes ~3.5 minutes.

```
fooB <- foo %*% foo
```

The second time, with a lower threshold..... number of 1's : 30,384,683 ... Number of 0's : 3,886,998,238. Sum of these is again, 62589^2, and therefore truly binarised. The Rdata Object is 84Mb. Performing the same multiplication step as above is still currently calculating after an hour.

Should the increased number of 1's in the newest matrix increase the file size and processing time so drastically?

Thanks for reading

Edit: final time for same calculation to second matrix is 65 minutes

Edit2: performing is() results in : Matrix Array Structure Vector

Comment: Is it possible that some matrix mult algorithms are "smart" in that they detect when entire columns/rows are 0, which can save quite a few loops, potentially?

Comment: Why not to use `sparse.matrix` to see the difference?

Comment: these must be sparse matrices (as indicated by your `is()` results, and by the fact that you couldn't possibly manage to do this with dense matrices).  Therefore it's not particularly surprising.  This is a pretty hard problem!  I don't know whether it's straightforward to do fill-reducing permutations -- but that would only help if you were going to do multiplications on many matrices with the same structure.  The other possibility would be to try to do parallelized computations -- I don't know if there's an easy interface to BLAS for sparse, parallel binary matrix multiplication ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example that may help with memory size and processing times for binary sparse matrices from package `Matrix`:

```
n <- 62589

N1 <- 425491

require(Matrix)

foo <- sparseMatrix(i=sample(n, N1, TRUE), j=sample(n, N1, TRUE), dims=c(n, n))

print(object.size(foo), units="Mb")
#1.9 Mb
sum(foo)
#[1] 425464
```

(Note that the sampling may give some duplicates in pairs (i,j), thus the number above is slightly less than `N1`.)

Squaring:

```
system.time(fooB <- foo %*% foo)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.39    0.03    0.42

print(object.size(fooB), units="Mb")
#11.3 Mb
sum(fooB)
#[1] 2892234
```

Cubing:

```
system.time(fooC <- fooB %*% foo)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.74    0.11    2.87 

print(object.size(fooC), units="Mb")
#75 Mb
sum(fooC)
#[1] 19610641
```